# HP Pavilion can't see TP Link WPA4420 Wireless extender - but can see other WiFi

Tags: wifi-configuration

I have a HP Pavilion 15-n268ea, containing Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter (Driver version:  2023.15.701.2015).

I have bought a TP Link WPA4420 Powerline Extender, with WiFi as the place I want to use the laptop has a poor reception to the router.

I have set up the TP Link correctly - and this can now be seen and connected to from all my devices (phones, tablets etc) except for my laptop! The laptop can connect to the internet router when I'm close to it - so I know the laptop WiFi is working.

Why might the laptop not be able to see the TPLink? I've installed a WiFi analyser on my phone and it can see the TPLink network, on a channel with no other devices using (channel 6); but if I use a wifi Analyser on the laptop, it doesn't see anything at all on channel 6.

Laptop Can't see it:
[image: Can't see it]
Phone can see it:
[image: Can see it]

TPLink settings:
[image: Settings]

The laptop Wifi driver is up to date from hp.com.

Is there anything I can try please?

Comment: The WiFi device in your laptop supports 2.4GHz only. It doesn't even "see" 5GHz networks.

Comment: As far as I understand the TPLink supports 2.4 and 5GHz. Added an image of the TPLink settings